# Is it ok to post links to Tumblr?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, images

I would like to post a link to a screenshot, hosted on Tumblr.

Is it appropriate?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do that, but it's preferable that you use Stack Exchange's built-in image upload by clicking the image button in the editor toolbar or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> while writing a post.

That way, there's a lower risk of the link going dead and the screenshot disappearing and leaving your post with a broken image.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this, but why not use the built in image hosting service accessed via the Image option (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)?

This way your image will always be available.

Comment: Dammit Chris. 20 seconds. :P

Comment: I had never added an image before, I hadn't even seen the "Image option" but thanks!

Comment: Note that you can upload image based on URL i.e. image already hosted elsewhere, you don't have to download it first to your machine. :)

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not appropriate at all.

StackOverflow offers a premium hosting account with imgur.com, which ensures the image won't be lost due to link rot.  Hosting your image somewhere else means that it is likely your post will become useless in time.

Also, nobody wants to go to your tumblr.  Posting links to images hosted on your tumblr account can be considered spam, and may attract spam flags.  The community is very sensitive to anything that appears like self-promotion.